# How can I see the results from "top" command in ubuntu in a human readable format?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I would like to get the output from the "top" command in *MB*, as you get them using "du -h". I know that:

```
top -M
```

[should do the job](https://serverfault.com/questions/192802/how-to-have-linux-top-command-show-memory-summary-in-megabytes-not-kilobytes/246148#246148?newreg=819cd83058b1417d9c445b96232ac291), but on ubuntu instances I receive the following message:

```
top: unknown option 'M'
```

Is there another command that can be used or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One of the comments in the provided link says it works for fedora, not ubuntu.

Comment: It also works on MacOS. Is there way to  be obtained in ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can launch top and then cycle through memory units by pressing `shift-E` in ubuntu.

Do this:

`top`

`shift-E` until you see `MiB Mem` at the top.

`shift-W` saves your settings as default to `~/.toprc`

Comment: You are right `shift-E` changes the display for the overall information. As well, `E` does make the change for the information of each process. Thank you!